# In C#, What is the purpose of enclosing the method within this class?

Tags: c#, oop, programming-languages, methods

I am new to C#. What is the purpose of placing the main() method within a "class". 
No object is going to be created for this "so-called" class.  I don't know why they are looking at the entire program as classes and methods. Also why is the main() function called a method? Obviously it is in the class, but I always referred to it as a function.  Like this:

```
using System;
public class MyApp // What is the purpose of this class?
{
  public static void main() // Why is this called a method & not a function when no objects use it?
  {
    //Statements Here
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically, a function is something that returns a value.  The meaning loosened a bit in the context of procedural programming, where a function could have side effects without actually producing any value (this is arguably abuse of the term).  The term 'method' is neutral in meaning, so you would call this a method or a procedure (a method without a return value), rather than a function.

Answer (score 10):

In C#, there are no pure (naked) functions; all executable code exists in the context of a class.  A class' executable members (functions) are called methods.  It's just the way things are defined in the language.

This is pretty standard nowadays for Object Oriented Programming; you may want to research more about it.

Comment: I looked a little bit at Objective-C and I have not come across the idea of placing the main() method within a class. I am just a little confused what the point of this class is. No instances are going to be created for this class. Could you explain the purpose of that class without any instances further?

Comment: An interesting side note is that this is not a .NET restriction.  The CLR allows you to define a 'global method' within the context of an assembly module.  I'm guessing this was primarily for compatibility with VB.  With C#, they opted to eliminate this additional scope for method definitions.  You can still access this scope from C# using `global::`.

Comment: @ispeakcode, static classes are intended for conceptual grouping of related methods in a particular named scope, such as the 'Math' static class.  The alternative is to have 'static' functions at namespace scope, but this can quickly lead to pollution of the active scope with hundreds of utility functions as you start `using` namespaces.

Comment: @Dan Bryant do the purpose of enclosing the main() method with a class is because you can have multiple main() methods with different classes.  Only one main() method can run when the program is created, but the class can be specified during runtime.  Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @ispeakcode, That is actually possible, but it's not the primary intention.  The primary intention is to help organize complexity (as is the primary intention of most language features.)  The fact that you put Main() inside a class is just a side effect of the decisions made in C# as to how that organization is accomplished.

Comment: @ispeakcode, keep in mind that Objective-C is built directly on top of the C language and so must adhere to C's rules.  However, the actual entry point for the user code is really in your AppDelegate, which is a class, containing an entry method called application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (or a variant of this).  So even Objective-C is architecturally adhering to this object oriented design choice.

Comment: @Dan Bryant so the fact that you can't import individual names from a class as opposed to a namespace (and thus can't import all of them with a wildcard) is being sold as an *advantage* here? Doctor, it hurts when I pollute the current namespace...

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of placing the main() method within a "class"

C# is an object-oriented language. That is, every method must belong to a class.

> No object is going to be created for this "so-called" class.

Consider this perfectly valid code.

The class Dog has some functionality, weight, name, etc. It also contains a main method from where several instances of the Dog class are created and used.

The main method is just a special method, from where the application will load.

```
public class Dog
{
    int weight;
    int name;

    public static void main (string[] args)
    {
        Dog myDog = new Dog();
        myDog.weight = 15;
        myDog.name = "Fido";

        Console.WriteLine("MyDog Name: {0} Weight: {1}", myDog.weight, myDog.name);

        Dog bigDog = new Dog();
        bigDog.weight = 100;
        bigDog.name = "Beethoven";

        Console.WriteLine("BigDog Name: {0} Weight: {1}", bigDog.weight, bigDog.name);
    }
}
```

> Also why is the main() function called a method?

Function/Method same thing...

Answer (score 0):

u must have one `main()` method for run
also u can have multiple apart class with own `void main()` for testing this class

Answer (score 0):

In vb they distinguish functions from subroutines.  In c# if it has a return value other than void, the method can be considered a function like in vb.  Since there is no word method, the name main is considered to be a method if its inside a class construct and constructed correctly. The thing that starts the method construct is { You can only return void in a main method that has void as its return type, or just type return at any point and it will immediately go to the end of the main method's construct... }